# C# UserControl - Adding them at runtime

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, runtime

I'm writing a c#/WPF app. I'll have a list container on my window full of user controls that the user can select from. What I'd like to do is have a folder where I put my user controls. My main app would look at this folder location on startup for all user controls and then add them to the list container. This would allow me to create new user controls and drop them in a location the app knows to look for. Anyone have any guidance/direction on the best way to handle this?

I'm guessing my folder would be something like:
usercontrols/
usercontrols/controlOne
usercontrols/controlTwo
usercontorls/newControl

etc...

Thanks for any help

Comment: `have a folder where I put my user controls.` : do you mean the assemblies containing user controls? or the raw xaml files?

Comment: jberger: I don't actually know, have not tried this before, and I don't know yet what I'll need or how it will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `XamlReader` to load snippets of Xaml markup during runtime.

Here's an example:

```
void AddDynamicContent(string path, Panel panelToAddContent)
{

  DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(path);
  if (di.Exists)
  {
    FileInfo[] fileInfos = di.GetFiles("*.xaml");
    foreach (FileInfo fi in fileInfos)
    {

      XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(fi.FullName);
      FrameworkElement dynamicContent = (FrameworkElement)XamlReader.Load(xmlReader);
      panelToAddContent.Children.Add(dynamicContent);
    }
  }
}

...

AddDynamicContent(@"c:\temp\controls", myStackPanel);
```

Be sure to omit the class declaration part in your markup definitions (x:Class="") otherwise you'l get an exception. 
And please note that CodeBehind is not executed, it just creates a simple UIElement.